# Lazy Loading prevent the search or filter in my app (flutter & firestore)

Tags: flutter, firebase, search, filter, lazy-loading

I am new with flutter,
I would be grateful if you could help me with this problem:
I have a huge set of firestore data that I have to display i a listview, so I had to use Lazy Loading when I used it, the problem appeared, and I can't search or filter in all the data, only the data shown
so I need to use lazy Load or pagination and in the same time can search or filter all the firestore data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oesja.jpg)
and
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKfPl.jpg)

```
void initState() {
_chatScrollController = ScrollController()
  ..addListener(() {
    if (_chatScrollController!.position.atEdge) {
      if (_chatScrollController!.position.pixels == 0)
        ;
      else {
        setState(() {
          loadMoreMsgs = loadMoreMsgs + a;
        });
      }
    }
  });
super.initState();
```

}

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(kProductsCollection)
          .limit(loadMoreMsgs)
          .snapshots(),

builder: (context, snapshots) {
        return (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                controller: _chatScrollController,
                itemCount: snapshots.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var data = snapshots.data!.docs[index].data()
                      as Map<String, dynamic>;
                  List<Product> products = [];
                  for (var doc in snapshots.data!.docs) {
                    products.add(
                      Product(
                        pId: doc.id,
                        pName: doc.get(kProductName),
                        pPrice: doc.get(kProductPrice),
                        pUrl: doc.get(kProductUrl),
                        pIngredients: doc.get(kProductIngredients),
                        pCompany: doc.get(kProductCompany),
                        pDose: doc.get(kProductDose),
                        pCode: doc.get(kProductCode),
                        pClass: doc.get(kProductClass),
                        pCountry: doc.get(kProductCountry),
                        pDescription: doc.get(kProductDescription),
                        pPregnancyCategory:
                            doc.get(kProductPregnancyCategory),
                      ),
                    );
                  }

                  if (products[index]
                      .pName
                      .toString()
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 20, 5),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProductDetalis.id,
                                arguments: products[index]);
                          },
                          child: CardWidget(
                              width: width, height: height, data: data)),
                    );
                  }
```

Comment: please provide the snippet code instead the screen shoot of your code

Comment: I'm sorry I added the snippet